# Swiftui - How do I initialize an observedObject using an environmentobject as a parameter?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, xcode11

I'm not sure if this is an antipattern in this brave new SwiftUI world we live in, but essentially I have an @EnvironmentObject with some basic user information saved in it that my views can call.

I also have an @ObservedObject that owns some data required for this view.

When the view appears, I want to use that @EnvironmentObject to initialize the @ObservedObject:

```swift
struct MyCoolView: View { 

    @EnvironmentObject userData: UserData
    @ObservedObject var viewObject: ViewObject = ViewObject(id: self.userData.UID)  

    var body: some View { 
            Text("\(self.viewObject.myCoolProperty)")
    } 
}
```

Unfortunately I can't call self on the environment variable until after initialization:

> "Cannot use instance member 'userData' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available."

I can see a few possible routes forward, but they all feel like hacks. How should I approach this?

Comment: Maybe you can try adding a custom `init` to the struct.

Comment: I tried that and got a somewhat strange error:


`Property wrappers are not yet supported on local properties`

Basically its saying I cant create an @ObservedObject in an init method.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here is the approach (the simplest IMO):

```
struct MyCoolView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData

    var body: some View {
        MyCoolInternalView(ViewObject(id: self.userData.UID))
    }
}

struct MyCoolInternalView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
    @ObservedObject var viewObject: ViewObject

    init(_ viewObject: ViewObject) {
        self.viewObject = viewObject
    }

    var body: some View {
            Text("\(self.viewObject.myCoolProperty)")
    }
}
```

Comment: This is perfect. The MyCoolView was actually a child to a 'home' view where I declared the ObservedObject. Thanks!

Comment: But what if you want to manipulate the userData inside ViewObject without an entirely new ViewObject being created every time?

Answer (score 0):

One way to initialize `ObservableObject` that depends on environment (key or object) is to pass the necessary environment from a parent view via a view `init` that will itself create the `StateObject` using `wrappedValue:` initializer.

###### Solution

```
struct FirstScreen: View {
  @Environment(\.fooService) var fooService
  
  var body: some View {
    content
      .sheet(...) {
        SecondScreen(
          // Here we DO have access to environment
          fooService: fooService
        )
      }
  }
}

struct SecondScreen: View {
  @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel

  init(fooService: FooService) {
    // The ObservableObject initialisation is encapsulated here
    self._viewModel = .init(
      // The autoclosure initializer needs to be used
      wrappedValue: .init(fooService: fooService)
    )
  }
}
```

###### Disclosure

Following is a link to my article describing the solution in more detail:

[ObservableObject initialisation using Environment](https://medium.com/@pavel-holec/observableobject-initialisation-from-environment-2efa054de06d)

Comment: As I commented in another one of your answers, you **must explicitly** disclose any affiliation you have with sites you link.