# SwiftData refer to modelContext outside the view

Tags: swift, swiftui

For some reason I create the class manager that will handle somethings, inside this class I need to refer to the modelContext in order to do some complex filtering that I don’t want to do on the view but I’m bit stuck how can I refer on the class manager to the swiftdata maincontext as

```
Cannot use instance member 'modelContext' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
```

Here my code reproducible:

```
import SwiftUI


enum ViewType {
    case start
    case playlist
}

struct StartView: View {
    @State private var currentView: ViewType = .playlist
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @StateObject var manager = Manager(context: modelContext) // error here
    
    var body: some View {
        switch currentView {
            
        case .playlist:
            PlaylistView( manager: manager)
        case .start:
            Text("Start")
        }
    }
}
```

So inside manager I need to refer to modelContext , how can I refer to that outside the view ?

```
import Foundation
import SwiftData


@Observable
class Manager : ObservableObject {
    
    var context : ModelContext
 
    init(context: ModelContext) {
        self.context = context
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59367218/swiftui-how-do-i-initialize-an-observedobject-using-an-environmentobject-as-a